# Hibernate Envers @NotAudited annotation

Tags: hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers

On an Envers Audited class I am excluding a field by putting the @NotAudited annotation but Envers ignores my annotation, it only work on getter methods not on the field level.

Can I configure so I can place my annotations on field level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Envers looks for annotations in the same place where Hibernate annotations are. So if you have Hibernate mappings on fields, Envers will look at fields.

If you are using xml configuration, then most probably Envers is using the default method for searching for annotations, that is, on getters/setters.

Comment: Cheers, yes I am using xml mapping.